# Flutter : How to create NEXT button from JSON data?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, here is my detailDoaPage.dart that shown detailed item from a ListView.builder (based on my JSON local data) in previous page. In this detailed page, I want to create a button (Next button below) that change all attributes of this current data into next item. So the page isn't navigating, just changed the item inside it into the next data.

[image]

Anyone can help me to give me some advices for this problem? Here's my full code if you want to see it https://replit.com/join/nlmxirvq-nabilrei

Thank you :)

Comment: how do you handle your state?

Comment: to change all of items in the Card widget into next item. I've created Doa class that contains JSON data. So, this button state is to moved the current item into next item

Comment: check my answer below. would you mind sharing Doa class too?

Comment: Okay, i've added Doa class in my repl.it link

Answer (score 0):

Your `onPressed` callback method in the button is empty, you need to implement it in order to trigger state change when the button is pressed.

Something like this:

```dart
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  onPressed: () {
                      // here you would implement your logic, 
                      // whether be it calling an Api to fetch data, 
                      // or do some action on your data..Etc.
                      _functionToTriggerStateChange();
                  },
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  icon:
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded, color: Colors.teal),
                  splashColor: Colors.teal.withOpacity(0.3),
                  label:
                      Text("Next", style: Style(styleColor: Colors.teal).body),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: Yes, i want to create a function to trigger state change in my button to move to next item. But how can I implement it?

Comment: how do you load the first json entry ?

Comment: from Doa class, then I call it in every page that I want to use this JSON

Comment: from Doa class, then I call it in every page that I want to use this JSON

Comment: try adding a getById() function in Doa.dart, and each time you click next you call that function with the next id and affect the result to change the current doa. If there is no way to get the next id, then add a getNext(Doa current); and search for index of current, and return the doa in the next index.